# iOS Google Drive API load all GTLDriveFile from specified folder

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I just started using Google Drive API. I walked throughout installation and setup guide and right now I can use this beautiful service on my iOS application.

My goal is: load all files for specified directory.

I have found example how to get load filed for the root directory and it works perfect, I really like this code:

```
- (void)loadDriveFiles
{
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];

    query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' IN parents ", @"root"];

    [self.driveService executeQuery:query
                  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                      GTLDriveFileList *files,
                                      NSError *error)
    {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            _driveFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [_driveFiles addObjectsFromArray:files.items];

            for (GTLDriveFile *file in _driveFiles)
            {
                NSLog(@"title: %@", file.title);
                NSLog(@"mimeType: %@", file.mimeType);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

For load all files I have init `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` with `kGTLAuthScopeDrive` instead of `kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile` as they use for quick start [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart).

So the code above works perfect as I said, but my question is how I can replace "root" with folder id. I suppose that the `GTLDriveFile` object has this information, but I still have not find it. I figured out with mimeType, so I can check if the `GTLDriveFile` is a folder or not using this key/value:

```
mimeType:"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
```

but where can I find folder id? so I just played with hardcode folder id copying it from browser and it also worked for me, but I want to create table with cells which will contain folder id info, and by pressing this cell I will open folder based on the folder id that cell belongs. For this I need to know how to find folder id as I suppose. I think the users from android group also can suggest something.

Comment: You need the `file.identifier` of the parent folder. Use that instead of "root" in the query.

Comment: oh this is simples as even I expected thank you. you are right!